# Старый порядок слов в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, порядок-слов

Читая старую литературу, часто встречаешь инверсивные обороты: "... Малюта и *опричники его* направляли свой бег", "Поганая Лужа сделалась достоянием *силы нечистой*" (А. К. Толстой "Князь Серебряный") (определение ставится после определяемого слова).

В связи с этим вопрос: в чем заключаются основные отличия порядка слов в предложении, к примеру, XVIII — начала XX вв. от современного?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь это, если можно так сказать, эмфатическая инверсия.

Строго говоря, её и инверсией нельзя назвать, поскольку в русском языке нет жесткого порядка слов.

Такое встречается и в наши дни, примеры найдете сами - едва ли не в любом стихотворении.

С другой стороны, совершенно верно было сказано, что этот вопрос относится к стилистике. Помимо поэтической речи порядок слов, в чем-то отличный от современного, был принят в деловом письме и крупноформатной (эпической) прозе. Вот пожалуй в деловом письме изменения заметны более всего. Но конкретика этих изменений - это отдельный разговор. Более или менее очевидно то, что сказуемое тяготело там к концу фразы. Определение же шло после определяемого тогда только, когда на определение падал логический смысл, что и подчеркивалось такой "инверсией". В остальном уже действовали законы более контекстные, чем формальные, а само составление деловых бумаг было более искусством, чем навыком.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что Ваш вопрос больше относится к литературным стилям. Когда А. К. Толстой создавал свое произведение,  другие авторы  писали привычным нам порядком слов.
Например, Тургенев "Записки охотника":

> Он был высокого роста, плечист и сложен на славу. Из-под мокрой замашной рубашки выпукло выставлялись его могучие мышцы. Черпая курчавая борода закрывала до половины его суровое и мужественное лицо; из-под сросшихся широких бровей смело глядели небольшие карие глаза. Он слегка уперся руками в бока и остановился передо мною. Я поблагодарил его и спросил его имя.

И наши современники в XXI веке тоже могут ставить определение перед определяемым словом.
Всё зависит от стиля литературы.

Comment: "И наши современники в XXI веке тоже могут ставить определение перед определяемым словом" — а не наоборот? Сейчас вроде нормальный порядок слов: определение + определяемое.

Comment: Да, действительно! Перепутал "перед" с "после".))